# Configuring Pipeline dependencies in Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have 2 Azure Pipelines, `deploy` and `test`. As their names imply one is used for deploying a product and the other is used for testing. When a developer wants to run their own tests on the existing deployment they trigger `test`. When a deployment is required they trigger `deploy`. If the `test` pipeline is in execution when the `deploy` pipeline is triggered I want the `deploy` to wait till the `test` has finished executing.

Is there a way to configure this dependency within the pipeline.yaml themselves, or a workaround to achieve the mentioned requirement

Comment: Hi @Kevin Lu-MSFT, Sorry for the late response, I am in the process of trying out your solution, I actually have to write the querying process in bash instead of powershell which is why there maybe a small delay. But I tried executing a few curl commands to see the status and it should work. I will provide a confirmation on this ASAP

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to configure this dependency within the pipeline.yaml themselves, or a workaround to achieve the mentioned requirement

Here are two methods could meet your requirement:

1.You could add the [Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops) in your Yaml Pipeline. Add you could add **Invoke Rest API** check in the environment. Rest API: [Latest - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/latest/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1#buildstatus)

[image]

In Yaml Pipeline, you could call this environment.

Example:

```
stages:
- stage: deploy
  jobs:
  - deployment: DeployWeb
    displayName: deploy Web App
    pool:
      vmImage: 'Ubuntu-latest'
    environment: 'EnvironmentName'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          ...
```

When you run the pipeline, the environment will check the latest build status of the test Pipeline. If the build has completed , it will run the deploy pipeline.

**Result:**

[image]

2.You could directly add a Powershell task in the Deploy task to check the status of the Test Pipeline.

```
$token = "PAT"

$url="https://dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/{ProjectName}/_apis/build/definitions/{DefinitionID}?includeLatestBuilds=true&api-version=5.1"


$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))


$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get -ContentType application/json



$buildid = $response.latestBuild.id
echo $buildid


$success = $false

do{
    try{
    $Buildurl2 = "https://dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/{ProjectName}/_apis/build/builds/$($buildid)?api-version=5.0"


    $Buildinfo2 = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -ContentType application/json -Uri $Buildurl2 -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

    $BuildStatus= $Buildinfo2.status 
    $result = $Buildinfo2.result
    echo $result
    echo $BuildStatus


 
   
        if($BuildStatus -eq "completed"  ) {            

            write-output "No Running Pipeline, starting Next Pipeline"
            $success = $true 
                       
      } else {   
            Write-output "Pipeline Build In Progress, Waiting for it to finish!"  
            Write-output "Next attempt in 30 seconds"
            Start-sleep -Seconds 30         

            }
    
      
    }
    catch{
        Write-output "catch - Next attempt in 30 seconds"
        write-output "1"
        Start-sleep -Seconds 30
      # Put the start-sleep in the catch statemtnt so we
      # don't sleep if the condition is true and waste time
    }
    
    $count++
    
}until($count -eq 2000 -or $success -eq $true )
if ($result -ne "succeeded" )
{
   echo "##vso[task.logissue type=error]Something went very wrong."
}

if(-not($success)){exit}
```

You can also refer to [my another ticket.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65527879/13464420)

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to merge the pipelines into one and, depending on the steps in them, you can convert them to jobs or even to stages. In both cases, you can specify dependencies via `dependsOn` (e.g. [docs for jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?tabs=yaml&view=azure-devops#dependencies)).

So you will have something like:

```
jobs:
- job: test
  steps:
  - step1...
  - step2...

- job: deploy
  dependsOn: test
  steps:
  - step1...
  - step2...
```

Also, if you go this way, consider using [deployment jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs?view=azure-devops) for deployment, they have some related build-in functionality.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, Regarding your first suggestion, I was looking for away to do this with them as two separate pipelines, as there maybe instances where the test pipeline only needs to be executed. In such a case putting them in one would cause the deployment to be done again. I will look into deployment jobs also.

Comment: I see. It's also possible to specify [conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops) for particular pipeline parts, that may be of some use to your case.